# "Keep Data on Update" behaviour does not work in the Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

Whether I set the "Keep Data on Update" property true or false, it never affect.

If what I understand from this property is that it provides data on tables will be protected if it was set true, it does not work.

No matter what I did, all the data are deleted when I run the project.

How can I always save all the data on the database?

Answer (score 1):

keep data on Update is used for protecting the databases when you are updating your application whether you change the data structure or not. ( ex. 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1 )

For more information please check the link below;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/data-network/table/